# R how to get no. of cities search vs count of distinct visitorid

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
fullVisitorId  VisitId visitNumber City
1010122109733  1513354 1           Bangkok
1010164109733  1513366 8           Kuala Lumpur
1010122165452  1513354 5           Tokyo
1010198798713  1517773 10          Seoul
```

Using dplyr in R, how can I get

```
no. of cities searched | count of distinct visitorid
1                      | 500
2                      | 300
3                      | 10
```

I'll like to get no. of cities searched vs count of distinct visitorId

Comment: Not clear about the `no. of cities searched`.   What is the criteria for that column?  Does that include more than 3?

Comment: yes it includes more than 3. but we can use top() to filter later on.

Comment: Sorry, the logic is not clear to me.  Is it randomly select 3 cities?.  If you can show the expected output based on the input, it would be more clear rather than random numbers as expected

Comment: Eg. visitor 1010122109733 could have done 3 searches: Bangkok, Bangkok, Kuala Lumpur, and visitor 1010122165452  could have also done 3 searches: Tokyo, Tokyo, Tokyo. So no. of cities searched = 3 and count of distinct visitorid = 2.

Comment: As the expected output is not for the input, not clear.  May be `df1 %>% group_by(fullVisitorId) %>%  summarise(ncities = n_distinct(City), countdistinctvisitorid = n_distinct(fullVisitorId)) %>% top_n(countdistinctvisitorid, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to group by 'fullVisitorId', `summarise` by getting the number of distinct 'City' as well as the distinct 'fullVisitorId', and apply `top_n`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(fullVisitorId) %>% 
   summarise(ncities = n_distinct(City), 
             countdistinctvisitorid = n_distinct(fullVisitorId)) %>% 
   top_n(countdistinctvisitorid, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
ncities_searched <- data %>%
   group_by(fullVisitorId) %>% 
    summarise(ncities_searched = n_distinct(City)) %>% 
      count(ncities_searched)
```